# Using ajax to read text data from an outside source

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

So I am working on something that would allow me to read JSON data from an outside server, and print it out in a more human-readable format. So far I have this:

```
var address = "example.com"; 
              //not the actual site
$.ajax({
  url: address,
  dataType: "JSONP",
  success: function(data) 
  {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    //Misc printing code goes here
  },
  error: alert("Error")
});
```

However, I am consistently receiving the error alert.
The console tells me "Unexpected token &". Looking at a few other sources, the issue seems to be that the actual data present on the site is nothing more than raw text.
I changed the dataType field to "text" to try and fix this, but the console error instead changed to tell me that I wasn't allowed access.
I tried retrieving the data and treating it as text with "JSONP text", but it simply returned to the previous "Unexpected token &" error.
Is there any way I can receive text data from an outside server? If not, is there some workaround I could use, such as saving the data to a document and importing it into my code from there?

Comment: Change dataType to 'text' and display it. Perhaps it is not a valid JSON

Comment: I tried changing dataType to "text", and my console error changed to say I wasn't allowed access

Comment: Can you output "data" in the console "console.log(data);" to see what it contains on success?

Comment: can you post json source ?

Comment: I cannot post the full source, as it contains personal information, but here's a modified snippet:     
{ "Accounts": {
 "RowCount": "1",
 "FieldNames": "example",
 "Row":
 [
  {"name": "example", "value": "123"}
 ]
}} edit: also, I have now placed console.log(data); in the success conditions, but it does nothing as it is still returning the error condition

Comment: Right my mistake; it seems the json array is HTML encoded by the server, see if you can get it to not encode when sending